Check Kubernetes zone spread for pods in Prometheus
I'm trying to write a promql query which will show the spread between zones for pods in specific namespace regex. Right now I have
abs(
  (
    count by (namespace) (
      kube_pod_info{namespace=~"app-.*"} 
        * on(node) group_left() 
        topk(1, kube_node_labels{label_topology_kubernetes_io_zone="us-east-1a"}) by (node)
    )
  )
  -
  (
    count by (namespace) (
      kube_pod_info{namespace=~"app-.*"} 
        * on(node) group_left() 
        topk(1, kube_node_labels{label_topology_kubernetes_io_zone="us-east-1b"}) by (node)
    )
  )
)

But it doesn't work when there are no pods in one of the zones. Then again I think my approach is faulty, because I think I should list namespaces first and then check for pods in these namespaces. Right now kube_pod_info won't return anything for one of the counts and it won't have the knowledge about specific namespace, even if the other count returns something for this namespace. Therefore even or on() vector(0) won't work.
I need a query to show what is the spread between zones for pods in namespaces with app prefix when there is at least 1 pod in this namespace. Dynamic resolution of zones would be amazing as well.
